# Why getView Method give nullpointer Exception?

Tags: android

I am making a listview which have two section both section have different xml but my getView method is not working give following exception:-

```
10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):    at    android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1594)
 10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):   at an droid.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1782)
 10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
 10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1619)
 10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1422)
 10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at andr oid.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at  android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
  10-03 14:34:29.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11029):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using this code:-

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(issection)
    {
        issection=false;
        convertView=null;   
    }

    if (convertView == null) {

        final MyJobListModle objitem = data.get(position);

        if (objitem != null && objitem.getIssection()!=null && !objitem.getIssection().equals("")) {


            if (objitem.getIssection().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                convertView = objinflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewsection,
                        null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                issection=true;
                convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
                convertView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                convertView.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtsection);
                sectionView.setText(objitem.getHeader_title());
            }

        }
        else
        {
        convertView = objinflater.inflate(R.layout.postjobrow, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.objjobname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textjob);
        holder.objbidalerts = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textalert);
        holder.objclick =(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textalertclick);
        holder.bidalerttext=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.alerttext);
        holder.objarrowimageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imagearrow);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    }else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    /*----  Handle click on listview item   ----*/
    if(holder!= null && holder.objarrowimageView!=null)
    {
    holder.objarrowimageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String jobcode = data.get(position).getId();
            Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
            Intent objintent = new Intent(objactivity,EditPostJobSection.class);
            objbundle.putString("jobid",jobcode);
            objbundle.putString("from","myjobadapter");
            objbundle.putString("createdAt",data.get(position).getCreated());
            objintent.putExtras(objbundle);
            objactivity.startActivity(objintent);
        }
    });
    }
    if(holder!= null && holder.objclick!=null)
    {
    holder.objclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String bidcount = data.get(position).getBid_count();
            if(!bidcount.equals("0"))
            {
                System.out.println("ok");
                ArrayList<JobBidAlertModle> objjobbidalertlist = data.get(position).getObjbidalertmodlelist();  
                Bundle objbunlde = new Bundle();
                Intent objintent = new Intent(objactivity,MyJobBidAlerts.class);
                objbunlde.putSerializable("objbidalertlist", objjobbidalertlist);
                if(data!=null && data.size()>position)
                {
                    objbunlde.putString("title",data.get(position).getTitle()); 
                }
                objbunlde.putString("createdAt",data.get(position).getCreated());
                objbunlde.putString("from","myjobadapter");
                if(data!=null && data.size()!=0)
                    {
                    objbunlde.putString("lat",data.get(position).getLocationlat());
                    objbunlde.putString("longi",data.get(position).getLocationlongi());
                    }
                objintent.putExtras(objbunlde);
                objactivity.startActivity(objintent);
            }
            if(bidcount.equals("0"))
            {

            }


        }
    });

    }

    if(holder!= null && holder.objjobname!=null && holder.objbidalerts!=null )
    {
    holder.objjobname.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    String bidcount = data.get(position).getBid_count();
    if(bidcount.equals("0"))
    {
        holder.objbidalerts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.objbidalerts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.objbidalerts.setText(bidcount);  
    }
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

When I execute null pointer occure.I am unable to troubleshooting what exact problem.
please anyone suggest me.thanks lot

Comment: Can u recheck your log cat and see exactly from which line your package starts in log cat. Double click that line and tell us which line it is pointing. Null pointer exception is most common exception and rises when u try access null variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have defined `TextView` with id `R.id.txtsection` in `listviewsection.xml` file.